# Game development: Are in-game interrupts ever used?

Tags: software-design

I'm learning game development, and the tutorials tell me to put everything in a while (1) loop. However, this is discouraged in embedded systems, where it's better if everything is treated as an interrupt.

Does this same concept apply in game development? I feel as if adding everything into a continuous loop would slow down a game significantly.

Comment: if everything is handled by interrupts, then what do you think the program is doing while waiting for interrupts?

Comment: @jsotola running background tasks

Comment: running in a loop, doing background tasks ... a loop such as `while (1)`

Comment: @jsotola Right, so what's your point? Did you assume I was saying get rid of an entire while loop? The game wouldn't even be running without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. My understanding of interrupts is that they are exclusively in relation to hardware. Most games are built with game development frameworks so the engineer working on the game is not getting anywhere near the hardware. It would add substantial complexity to game development if they did have to do this.
2. Interrupts are for things which need to be handled immediately. While it may seem like the bullet from your gun in a first-person shooter might qualify, it really isn't that important. You may also be moving while shooting. There may be other players. The camera needs to re-render. The minimap needs to update. In a video game, I can't think of anything which takes enough precedence to justify interrupting the rest of the cycle.